# block a contact in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, sms, blocking, phonebook

I started developing an app to  block someone that already exists in the phonebook,
I know the iPhone can do it by itself, but I need this ability in my App
And also I know that I can block unknown senders programmatically
But the problem is with Known Senders that are in our phonebook
can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you want to block? Incoming calls?  Incoming messages?

Comment: both of them, I have a database with over 1000 phone number and I want to block them in both Messages and Phone  app

Comment: To block them in the phone you need to implement a call blocking extension using the CallKit framework https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial there is no way for your app to block messages from a user that is in the contacts. You can only block messages from an unknown sender. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting/sms_and_mms_message_filtering

Comment: I know about callKit extension and also about unknown senders, but I need to block a known sender for both of call & SMS just like iPhone regular blocking

Comment: You can't. Only the user can do that